# sessionStorage give as output [object HTMLElement]

Tags: javascript, json, session-storage

On my first.js document i got this code right down:

```
 let flags = [];
    
    function getFlag() {
        const x = document.querySelectorAll('.trigger');
        let random = x[Math.floor(Math.random() * x.length)];
    
        if (!flags.includes(random)) {
            random.classList.remove('trigger');
            flags.push(random);
        } else {
            if (x.length === flags.length) {
                console.log('finish!');
            }
        }
        sessionStorage.setItem("flagSelect", flags[0]);
        console.log(flags[0].children[0].innerHTML);
    }
```

while on second.js i got this:

```
let figaro = sessionStorage.getItem("flagSelect");

document.querySelector('.errore').innerHTML = figaro;
```

and it write down [object HTMLElement] and not the array's value.
Do you know why? D:

Comment: You need to use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`

Comment: you should not store the full reference to trigger instead store the random value as `x` can referenced later

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers, i searched for these JSON methods and i didn't  quite understand in which way should i use them. Do i need to create a json file?

Comment: const obj = JSON.parse(passyour data);

Comment: remove random.classList.remove('trigger');  this